# How to combine all dll's and make a single DLL?

Tags: c++, opencv, dll

How to combine all dll's and make a single DLL?

i have written an algorithm using Opencv, now i want to make a single dll while combines used opencv DLL's

If it is possible please suggest some steps.

Comment: Simple. Just take the source to all of the DLLs and create a single DLL project with all of them. Short of that http://www.binary-soft.com/dll2lib/dll2lib.htm might be helpful, but the task is not trivial nor guaranteed to be workable.

Comment: @mah: Wouldn't work, in general. Each DLL has its own `DllMain()`, and you would need to merge those. That's not a trivial task.

Comment: @MSalters I agree it's no trivial task and I don't know if it will work, but if that tool works as intended it might work. That tool converts a DLL to a static library (including dealing with DllMain, I expect); one could convert multiple DLLs and then build a single DLL with the results theoretically. I've used the tool in the past for single DLL conversions, with mixed results.

Comment: If OpenCV is available as static library, then you can statically link it to your DLL, and as a result generate single and independent (on OpenCV) DLL.

Answer (score 2):

First step is to find out if opencv supports static linkage (ie if you can link with its .lib without any of its .dlls). Most libraries don't. Most libraries could be made to support that by customizing (not trivial as already stated, but doable). This is a big if.

But assuming opencv supports static linkage, you need to compile it into a .lib (project of "Type Library" type). Then in your project (output type dll) that uses opencv, just link the opencv.lib.
Couple of caveats: make sure you use exactly the same Unicode settings and "code generation" CRT linkage (/MT or /MTD or /MD or /MDD) for all the projects, including opencv.

I could not find at a glance whether opencv supports static linkage.

Comment: You *can* rebuild OpenCV as static libs, so - as you say - you can in theory link everything statically into another DLL or EXE. +1 from me.